# Multiple Multipart file upload in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

> spring.http.multipart.max-file-size: 2MB
>
> spring.http.multipart.max-request-size: 2MB

If I am uploading multiple files in 1 request, will it total up the size of all files and allow 2MB only or it will allow each file up to 2MB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = 2MB
```

**Max size per file the upload supports is 2MB;**

also supports the MB or KB suffixes; 
by default 1MB

---

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

**max size of the whole request is 10MB;**

also supports the MB or KB suffixes

Comment: in your case it is http

Comment: In the case you mentioned request size 10MB.
So in the request I can add 5 files of max-size 2 mb, right?

Comment: @Tarun yes, even you can have 10 files of each 1 MB.